# Can I disable SlowCheetah transforms when running non-web application in Visual Studio

Tags: slowcheetah

I have SlowCheetah as part of my TeamCity build process to transform app.config files.

I know that in the case of web applications, running an application in local Visual Studio debugger does NOT transform the relevant web.config. I presumed this behaviour was the same for app.config files but I just found today that when I run a Console or Windows Service application from local VS 2012 (e.g. in Debugger) the app.config is transformed.

Is there a way to prevent the app.config transform occurring when running a non-WAP project in debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this.

Open the csproj file for the project (e.g. Windows Service project) in an editor (You can do right-click|Unload Project in the VS Solution Explorer followed by "Edit Project File" to edit the file contents in Visual Studio).

Look for the line containing the following:

```
<Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" Label="SlowCheetah" />
```

and modify it as follows:

```
<Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')and '$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'false'" Label="SlowCheetah" />
```

This will disable transforms when you are on your local machine but they will continue to be transformed in a Build Server.

Comment: why wouldn't I have that line?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I am not sure I understand your question. If you are asking why you would not have the SlowSheetahTargets line (the first code line above) then it would be because you have not referenced SlowCheetah.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli remember the best way to utilise SlowCheetah is via nuget. However, you will see the developer will not be doing any further development on SlowCheetah

Comment: Yeah, I'm really surprised this type of thing isn't just baked in to VS